# How to resolve url to method or view in flask

Tags: python, flask

Coming from django background I'm trying to get method for a specific url in flask.

In django,

```
from django.urls import resolve
resolve("/hello_world/") # returns view asssociated  /hello_world/
```

Is there is simlillar kind of functionality is available with flask that can return method against url?

Answer (score 0):

You could be after the `redirect` function.

```
from flask import redirect

def your_function():
    return redirect('/hello_world/')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the redirect method of flask

```py
from flask import redirect

@app.route('/hello_world/')
def home():
  return redirect("/") # Redirects to /
```

OR

You can use the `url_for` function of flask in combination with the `redirect` function to redirect using the method name of the view.

```py
from flask import redirect, url_for

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html') # Renders the template

@app.route('/hello_world/')
def hello():
   return redirect(url_for('index')) # Redirects to /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import redirect, url_for

@app.route('/')
def index():
  contex_variable = 5 # as sample
  return render_template('frontend.html', context = contex_variable) 
  # return render_template('frontend.html')
```

We can use the context we sent in the above code in the html template using jinja. You don't have to use context.

```
@app.route('/another_x/')
def another():

   # write code here
   return redirect(url_for('frontend')) # Redirects to /
```